# What do the $T, E, B$ in polarization spectra mean?

Tags: cosmology, polarization, cosmic-microwave-background

I was reading about CMB Polarization [here](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March05/Scott/Scott6.html). I know that $E$ and $B$ stand for [E-mode and B-mode](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104025/what-do-the-names-e-mode-and-b-mode-mean-where-do-they-come-from), but what does the $T$ mean? The author states that there are 3 observables: $T, E, B$ and six spectra: $TT$, $EE$, $BB$, $TE$, $TB$, $EB$ two of which ($TB$, $EB$) are zero because of parity (I don't understand this part). Can someone help me clarity this also?

Comment: One can analyze the mapping of the E and B components and T the temperature anisotropy by decomposing them in terms of spherical harmonics. Parity invariance demands that the _cross correlation between the pseudoscalar B and the scalars T or E vanishes_. [more and equations links](http://background.uchicago.edu/~whu/araa/node5.html)