# Why are not quadratic potentials suitable for simple inflationary models?

Tags: cosmology, potential-energy, cosmological-inflation

I am trying to understand why the simple inflationary model with potential $V(\phi) \propto \phi^2$ is disfavored compared to models predicting a smaller tensor-to-scalar ratio.

To do so I am reading [Planck 2015 results](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02114). In particular, I focused on "Power law potentials" subsection.

The issues I have are

1. I do not understand why the validity of the model can be determined by the value of the $B$ mode.
2. Why the $B$ mode values $\ln B = −11.6$ and $\ln B = −23.3$ for the cubic and quartic potentials, respectively, are regarded as "strongly disfavored" and $\ln B = −4.7$ for the quadratic potential as "moderately disfavored"? What I mean is: what is the threshold value at which we can consider the potential as favored and why?

Comment: related question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104025/85745

Comment: The B is not related to B-modes; it’s the Bayes factor comparing the particular inflation model to the $R^2$ model.  The numerical value of the Bayes factor is related to favorability ratings via the Jeffreys scale.